# How to export email addresses from Apple Mail?

Tags: export, email, email-client

When sending an email to someone in Apple Mail it remembers their address, so if you try and send another email to them it'll prompt you with it - even if you haven't added them to the address book.

Is there any way of exporting those remembered addresses, or saving them to the address book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mail, go to Window -> Previous Recipients. You can then add them to your Address Book. If you want to export the list to a file, you can do so in the Terminal by [directly accessing the sqlite database](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1695676) with sqlite3. Excerpt from link (formatting mine):

> This turns out to be more complicated than I had hoped, but it is possible.
>
> The Apple mail program uses a database program available in Unix called “sqlite3.”
>   The executable is in /usr/bin. For information about this program, type “man sqlite3” in a terminal window. Also, there is information on the web, at www.sqlite.org. A friend whose day job is in database administration helped me work this out.
>
> First, go the proper directory in a terminal window:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook
> ```
>
> The file of interest is MailRecents-v4abcdmr.
>
> Note that the `file` command describes this as:
>
> ```
> $ file MailRecents-v4abcdmr
> MailRecents-v4.abcdmr: SQLite database (Version 3)
>
> $ sqlite3 MailRecents-v4.abcdmr
> SQLite version 3.4.0
> Enter ".help" for instructions
> sqlite>
> ```
>
> Let’s see the headers:
>
> ```
> sqlite> .headers ON
> ```
>
> Now, let’s get some information about what’s in this database file:
>
> ```
> sqlite> select * from SQLITE_MASTER; /* don’t forget the semicolon */
> /* lots of output */
> ```
>
> The table `ZABCDMAILRECENT` is of interest to us. Note that the last 3 columns are called `ZLASTNAME`, `ZFIRSTNAME`, and `ZEMAIL`. We want these from the table, in columns, in filename.txt.
>
> ```
> sqlite> .mode columns ZABCDMAILRECENT
> sqlite> .width 15 15 36 /* make sure the columns are wide enough */
> sqlite> .output filename.txt /* note: no ‘;’ */
> sqlite:> select ZLASTNAME, ZFIRSTNAME, ZEMAIL from ZABCDMAILRECENT;
> sqlite> .exit
> ```
>
> Done. The email names and addresses are now in `filename.txt`, one per line.
>
> Maybe, someday, someone at Apple will add this capability to mail.

Answer (score 6):

If using OS X 10.10 use the following code as the location of the previous recipients file changed. I did some digging and this worked for me (the following is all one line):

```
sqlite3 -csv ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.corerecents.recentsd/Data/Library/Recents/Recents 'select display_name, address from contacts where kind like "email";'>~/Desktop/recent.csv
```

This new 'Recents' file contains ALL recent contacts including, FaceTime and iMessage recipients so an additional filter was added to only export e-mail contacts.

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly! Thank you so much for that!

Answer (score 4):

To export to a CSV file:

Run as one line:

> sqlite3 -csv ~/Library/Application\ 
>   Support/AddressBook/MailRecents-v4.abcdmr
>   'select ZLASTNAME, ZFIRSTNAME, ZEMAIL
>   from ZABCDMAILRECENT;'

To export to file "recent.csv":

> sqlite3 -csv ~/Library/Application\
>   Support/AddressBook/MailRecents-v4.abcdmr
>   'select ZLASTNAME, ZFIRSTNAME, ZEMAIL
>   from ZABCDMAILRECENT;'>recent.csv

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this was if you were looking for, but google brought me here when I was looking for it, so you can export all mail addresses on your Mail App like this:

```
sqlite3 -csv ~/Library/Mail/V7/MailData/Envelope\ Index 'SELECT comment, address FROM addresses;' > ~/Desktop/allAddresses.csv
```

You might have to grant privileges to the terminal like: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339626/error-unable-to-open-database-in-macos-mojave

Answer (score 1):

This is a stupid, but simple way to do it.

Mark all mails, choose print - but change to save to PDF, then export to Word, then export to TXT file format and start to filter the file with Text Wrangler.

Easy but stupid ;)

Comment: Can you please eloborate how to filter the file with text wrangler.