# Get list of all people I've e-mailed in Office 365

Tags: email, office365

When you e-mail someone in Office 365 (through webmail or Outlook client), it must "store" the recipient's address somewhere as when you then go to e-mail them later on their name can autocomplete in the address bar (e.g. if I've e-mailed sales@blah.com, I can then start typing a new e-mail and write "sa" into the address bar and it will suggest sales@blah.com).

Is there a way of getting a list of these e-mail addresses?

I'm basically trying to find a list of any e-mail addresses I have sent to in the past (preferably date-filtered, if this is possible). We're moving e-mail domains on fairly short notice so I'd like to show staff how to e-mail everyone they need to saying "please update your records, I'm now using X.Y@domain.com e-mail address".

**EDIT**: I am trying to get a list of my O365 users' *e-mail recipients*, e.g. people they have sent e-mails to, rather than a list of my O365 users' e-mail addresses.

Ideally I would like the users themselves to be able to do this - to get a list of e-mail addresses which they can then send a BCC'd e-mail to stating "I have changed e-mail address".

Comment: Can you export all emails to csv? Then use excel to filter?

Comment: Or export to pst http://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-export-office-365-mailboxes-to-pst-using-ediscovery/

Comment: Also, do you have both domains? If so then use OOO

Comment: This question has already been answered here
http://superuser.com/questions/50006/how-can-i-export-all-email-addresses-i-have-sent-to-from-outlook-or-any-other-em

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I export all email addresses I have sent to from Outlook or any other Email Client?](https://superuser.com/questions/50006/how-can-i-export-all-email-addresses-i-have-sent-to-from-outlook-or-any-other-em)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Here are steps for connecting to Office 365 in Powershell

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Enter username and password

```
Import-PSSession $session
```

Powershell gives you a great and easy tool to achieve such in a very few short steps

1) Connect to office 365 in Powershell

2) Run the below cmdlet

```
et-Recipient -ResultSize Unlimited | select DisplayName,RecipientType,EmailAddresses | Export-Csv email-recipients.csv
```

This puts the results in a CSV file for you.  Here is the full link if needed

https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/office-365-tips/export-all-email-addresses-from-office-356

Comment: Doesn't this just return all of the e-mail addresses in my O365 tenancy? I'm looking to do this for my O365 users to see who they have sent e-mails to - primarily outside the organisation.

Comment: Yes, it would return for the user credentials that were supplied.  Sorry, I read your post as you were wanting to provide your users a method on how to export email addresses.

Comment: Could be my mistake, I don't think I wrote the post well. I've included an edit to clarify.

Comment: So YOU want to query your mail server and get a list of ALL email addresses that have been mailed by any email account not just your own?

Comment: Only if I can separate it out by user, e.g. "me@mydomain.com has e-mailed blah@blah.com, blah@blah1.com" and "you@mydomain.com has e-mailed blah2@blah.com, blah@blah2.com" etc.

Comment: Is your mail server hosted locally or in the cloud?  If hosted locally, do you have an admin panel you can access that could provide you this ability?

Comment: It's a cloud-hosted O365 domain with Azure AD sync.

Comment: The cloud is a blessing and a curse...  Since it is cloud based you really have limited control over the "server" itself.  How many users?

Comment: If it's a Microsoft managed service you could try asking customer support to do it for you. <-- O(1) solution right there.