# Outlook 2013: export SMTP addresses of the Exchange contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

Outlook's 2013 Export to CSV doesn't output SMTP addresses of the Exchange contacts.
Is there a viable VBA or non-VBA workaround for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research, it seems to that we could implement it with exchange powershell, for detailed information, please refer to this thread: [How To Export a List of Only User Mailboxes with their Name and SMTP address?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/bc1d384a-3c6e-4d46-a248-53474b818b58/how-to-export-a-list-of-only-user-mailboxes-with-their-name-and-smtp-address?forum=exchange2010)

If you still would like to search for a script, [here](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/export-exchange-gal-excel/) is a script with VBA to Export Exchange GAL to Excel, please kindly check if it could also be helpful to you.

Comment: Seems to be working solutions. Thank you. However GAL requires an on-line connection, doesn't it? What I need is to simply export all non-emply fields from the contact card (for example, https://www.msoutlook.info/pictures/contact-card-clark-kent-2013.png). Is this possible?